# Identity among commutators.

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a proper normal subgroup of $G$ which is not the identity. For what class of groups $G$(not necessarily finite) do we have the following:  $[G,N]=[G,G]\cap N$, for some normal subgroup $N$. Of course this reminds us of the Hopf formula. I believe this will be true if $H_2(G/N)$ is trivial.

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is all groups $G$, with $N=G$, or with $N=1$. You probably intended to ask something different!

Comment: @DerekHolt, I want $N$ to be a proper normal subgroup other than the identity subgroup.

Comment: That's not stated in the question. It is also unclear whether you are asking specifically about finite groups, because you have the tag "finite-groups", but have not mentioned that in the question.

Comment: It's false in all simple groups. It's true in all groups with a non-central minimal normal subgroup, and also in all decomposable groups. But these are all obvious! I would be surprised if there was an exact characterization.